# iOS Swift -> Dismiss a View with ongoing Function

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

Sup guys!

I would like to dismiss the view and run the Firestore task in the background ... without blocking the UI or displaying a loading animation.

The code works like this .. but is there a better method or is it fine like that?

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        uploadImageFIR(image: image) { url in
        //FIRESTORE TASK HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "better" method?

Comment: I always want to learn something, and therefore ask whether the method as I use it is correct or whether it blocks maybe something?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.